# Bootstrap CSS not loading fonts correctly when hosted locally

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I currently have a webapp that currently looks something like this

**Directory**:

```
|-- index.jsp
|-- css
     |-- bootstrap.min.css
|-- fonts
     |-- glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
     |-- glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
     |-- glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
     |-- glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
     |-- glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
```

**index.jsp**:

```html
<html>
<head>
   <title>Login</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" /> -->
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
   <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <!-- <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> -->
</head>
<body>
   <input id="username" name="username" class="required" tabindex="1" placeholder="Username" type="text" /><span id="usernameTip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span>
   <input id="password" name="password" class="required" tabindex="2" placeholder="Password" type="password" /><span id="passwordTip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Temporarily, I'm using CDNs for my library files, but I'd like to be hosting the files locally. However, when I use the Bootstrap file locally, specifically the CSS, the glyphicons aren't appearing in IE10. After digging around a whole bunch, I noticed a discrepancy between when bootstrap.min.css was hosted on a CDN versus locally.

This is what I see when I use the IE Developer Tools in the Network tab

bootstrap.min.css from maxcdn:

```
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix   HTTPS   GET 200 application/vnd.ms-fontobject   20.14 KB    47 ms   @font-face  296 0   32  15  0   0
```

bootstrap.min.css from local directory:

```
/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?    HTTPS   GET 200     19.94 KB    31 ms   @font-face  2667    0   16  15  0   16
/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff    HTTPS   GET 200     23.16 KB    < 1 ms  @font-face  2698    0   0   0   0   16
/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf HTTPS   GET 200     44.62 KB    16 ms   @font-face  2698    0   16  0   0   0
```

I believe this is the root of the issue but I can't understand what would be causing it. I'm using the same version of Bootstrap locally, 3.3.2, and I noticed the issue occurs regardless of whether or not any of the other library files are hosted locally or on CDNs. Any combination of jQuery, jQueryUI, and Bootstrap sourced either externally or internally made no difference, except for when it was bootstrap.css.

Anyone able to shed some light on this issue?

Comment: The font files look like they are being served locally, given the 200 status. So is it that the icon looks like an empty square, something like that. What happens when you inspect the actual css in the console?

Comment: The icon doesn't show at all, but there's a space where it should be. So I guess it's an empty square. What exactly should I be looking for when I inspect the actual CSS? They're minified versions, so it's difficult to read, but they look identical at first glance.

Comment: Something like this I think. It's still difficult to tell though. http://s1.postimg.org/rc2x8uyb3/Screen_Shot_2015_01_23_at_16_58_56.png

Comment: [Here](http://i.imgur.com/pTpVL0U.png) is what it looks like when the CSS is sourced from MaxCDN. [This](http://i.imgur.com/6glmSbV.png) is what it looks like when it's sourced on the server. As far as I can tell, they're identical.

Comment: Try adding mime types types to your web server (IIS?) application/font-woff, application/font-woff2, etc.

Comment: Yeah I think there is an issue with the font file. I did think about adding the mime types, but I don't think you get a 200 status if the file is not configured in the mime type. I will try and look into it if I get some time.

Comment: I've tried downloading the font from MaxCDN directly and replacing the one I get from the .zip on Bootstrap's homepage, and still nothing. Could it have to do with how the server is handling the font request? I'm currently using Tomcat6 on a CentOS server.

Comment: Hello again. So I think it could be to do with a local issue relating to your server. Can you confirm what browser you are using, also what are you running for a local server environment. You might need to update a htaccess file and/or mime types. It would also help to see a console error for the font file (if one exists). Have a look here for related info: http://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/font-face-icon-font-not-working-in-firefox/

Comment: I'm using IE 11 on a Windows 7 computer to access the page, but the actual page is being hosted on a CentOS 6.5 server using Tomcat6. There doesn't seem to be any console error on the browser. I'm looking into that link now, thanks.

Comment: Yes I am fairly sure it will be something to do with the server configuration then. If you can access this you might be able to get the files to be served properly.

Comment: It seems that Tomcat6 doesn't use .htaccess and I'm not sure what else to be looking for exactly. I'm not terribly familiar with it yet as I've only been using it for a couple of months now.

Answer (score 11):

simply open web.config file and add this:

```
 <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
```

Now everything will work fine.

Answer (score 8):

I noticed in the 3.3.2 Sass version that the CSS for the glyphicons was incorrect.  In the bootstrap _glyphicons.scss file there were no quotes around the content: values.  When the files are compiled and rendered by various browsers the icons will not render.  You will need to update your CSS files with quotes.  I will try to paste my updated version below:

```
//
// Glyphicons for Bootstrap
//
// Since icons are fonts, they can be placed anywhere text is placed and are
// thus automatically sized to match the surrounding child. To use, create an
// inline element with the appropriate classes, like so:
//
// <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span> Star</a>

// Import the fonts
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: url(if($bootstrap-sass-asset-helper, twbs-font-path('#{$icon-font-path}#{$icon-font-name}.eot'), '#{$icon-font-path}#{$icon-font-name}.eot'));
  src: url(if($bootstrap-sass-asset-helper, twbs-font-path('#{$icon-font-path}#{$icon-font-name}.eot?#iefix'), '#{$icon-font-path}#{$icon-font-name}.eot?#iefix')) format('embedded-opentype'),
       url(if($bootstrap-sass-asset-helper, twbs-font-path('#{$icon-font-path}#{$icon-font-name}.woff'), '#{$icon-font-path}#{$icon-font-name}.woff')) format('woff'),
       url(if($bootstrap-sass-asset-helper, twbs-font-path('#{$icon-font-path}#{$icon-font-name}.ttf'), '#{$icon-font-path}#{$icon-font-name}.ttf')) format('truetype'),
       url(if($bootstrap-sass-asset-helper, twbs-font-path('#{$icon-font-path}#{$icon-font-name}.svg##{$icon-font-svg-id}'), '#{$icon-font-path}#{$icon-font-name}.svg##{$icon-font-svg-id}')) format('svg');
}

// Catchall baseclass
.glyphicon {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

// Individual icons
.glyphicon-asterisk               { &:before { content: "\2a"; } }
.glyphicon-plus                   { &:before { content: "\2b"; } }
.glyphicon-euro,
.glyphicon-eur                    { &:before { content: "\20ac"; } }
.glyphicon-minus                  { &:before { content: "\2212"; } }
.glyphicon-cloud                  { &:before { content: "\2601"; } }
.glyphicon-envelope               { &:before { content: "\2709"; } }
.glyphicon-pencil                 { &:before { content: "\270f"; } }
.glyphicon-glass                  { &:before { content: "\e001"; } }
.glyphicon-music                  { &:before { content: "\e002"; } }
.glyphicon-search                 { &:before { content: "\e003"; } }
.glyphicon-heart                  { &:before { content: "\e005"; } }
.glyphicon-star                   { &:before { content: "\e006"; } }
.glyphicon-star-empty             { &:before { content: "\e007"; } }
.glyphicon-user                   { &:before { content: "\e008"; } }
.glyphicon-film                   { &:before { content: "\e009"; } }
.glyphicon-th-large               { &:before { content: "\e010"; } }
.glyphicon-th                     { &:before { content: "\e011"; } }
.glyphicon-th-list                { &:before { content: "\e012"; } }
.glyphicon-ok                     { &:before { content: "\e013"; } }
.glyphicon-remove                 { &:before { content: "\e014"; } }
.glyphicon-zoom-in                { &:before { content: "\e015"; } }
.glyphicon-zoom-out               { &:before { content: "\e016"; } }
.glyphicon-off                    { &:before { content: "\e017"; } }
.glyphicon-signal                 { &:before { content: "\e018"; } }
.glyphicon-cog                    { &:before { content: "\e019"; } }
.glyphicon-trash                  { &:before { content: "\e020"; } }
.glyphicon-home                   { &:before { content: "\e021"; } }
.glyphicon-file                   { &:before { content: "\e022"; } }
.glyphicon-time                   { &:before { content: "\e023"; } }
.glyphicon-road                   { &:before { content: "\e024"; } }
.glyphicon-download-alt           { &:before { content: "\e025"; } }
.glyphicon-download               { &:before { content: "\e026"; } }
.glyphicon-upload                 { &:before { content: "\e027"; } }
.glyphicon-inbox                  { &:before { content: "\e028"; } }
.glyphicon-play-circle            { &:before { content: "\e029"; } }
.glyphicon-repeat                 { &:before { content: "\e030"; } }
.glyphicon-refresh                { &:before { content: "\e031"; } }
.glyphicon-list-alt               { &:before { content: "\e032"; } }
.glyphicon-lock                   { &:before { content: "\e033"; } }
.glyphicon-flag                   { &:before { content: "\e034"; } }
.glyphicon-headphones             { &:before { content: "\e035"; } }
.glyphicon-volume-off             { &:before { content: "\e036"; } }
.glyphicon-volume-down            { &:before { content: "\e037"; } }
.glyphicon-volume-up              { &:before { content: "\e038"; } }
.glyphicon-qrcode                 { &:before { content: "\e039"; } }
.glyphicon-barcode                { &:before { content: "\e040"; } }
.glyphicon-tag                    { &:before { content: "\e041"; } }
.glyphicon-tags                   { &:before { content: "\e042"; } }
.glyphicon-book                   { &:before { content: "\e043"; } }
.glyphicon-bookmark               { &:before { content: "\e044"; } }
.glyphicon-print                  { &:before { content: "\e045"; } }
.glyphicon-camera                 { &:before { content: "\e046"; } }
.glyphicon-font                   { &:before { content: "\e047"; } }
.glyphicon-bold                   { &:before { content: "\e048"; } }
.glyphicon-italic                 { &:before { content: "\e049"; } }
.glyphicon-text-height            { &:before { content: "\e050"; } }
.glyphicon-text-width             { &:before { content: "\e051"; } }
.glyphicon-align-left             { &:before { content: "\e052"; } }
.glyphicon-align-center           { &:before { content: "\e053"; } }
.glyphicon-align-right            { &:before { content: "\e054"; } }
.glyphicon-align-justify          { &:before { content: "\e055"; } }
.glyphicon-list                   { &:before { content: "\e056"; } }
.glyphicon-indent-left            { &:before { content: "\e057"; } }
.glyphicon-indent-right           { &:before { content: "\e058"; } }
.glyphicon-facetime-video         { &:before { content: "\e059"; } }
.glyphicon-picture                { &:before { content: "\e060"; } }
.glyphicon-map-marker             { &:before { content: "\e062"; } }
.glyphicon-adjust                 { &:before { content: "\e063"; } }
.glyphicon-tint                   { &:before { content: "\e064"; } }
.glyphicon-edit                   { &:before { content: "\e065"; } }
.glyphicon-share                  { &:before { content: "\e066"; } }
.glyphicon-check                  { &:before { content: "\e067"; } }
.glyphicon-move                   { &:before { content: "\e068"; } }
.glyphicon-step-backward          { &:before { content: "\e069"; } }
.glyphicon-fast-backward          { &:before { content: "\e070"; } }
.glyphicon-backward               { &:before { content: "\e071"; } }
.glyphicon-play                   { &:before { content: "\e072"; } }
.glyphicon-pause                  { &:before { content: "\e073"; } }
.glyphicon-stop                   { &:before { content: "\e074"; } }
.glyphicon-forward                { &:before { content: "\e075"; } }
.glyphicon-fast-forward           { &:before { content: "\e076"; } }
.glyphicon-step-forward           { &:before { content: "\e077"; } }
.glyphicon-eject                  { &:before { content: "\e078"; } }
.glyphicon-chevron-left           { &:before { content: "\e079"; } }
.glyphicon-chevron-right          { &:before { content: "\e080"; } }
.glyphicon-plus-sign              { &:before { content: "\e081"; } }
.glyphicon-minus-sign             { &:before { content: "\e082"; } }
.glyphicon-remove-sign            { &:before { content: "\e083"; } }
.glyphicon-ok-sign                { &:before { content: "\e084"; } }
.glyphicon-question-sign          { &:before { content: "\e085"; } }
.glyphicon-info-sign              { &:before { content: "\e086"; } }
.glyphicon-screenshot             { &:before { content: "\e087"; } }
.glyphicon-remove-circle          { &:before { content: "\e088"; } }
.glyphicon-ok-circle              { &:before { content: "\e089"; } }
.glyphicon-ban-circle             { &:before { content: "\e090"; } }
.glyphicon-arrow-left             { &:before { content: "\e091"; } }
.glyphicon-arrow-right            { &:before { content: "\e092"; } }
.glyphicon-arrow-up               { &:before { content: "\e093"; } }
.glyphicon-arrow-down             { &:before { content: "\e094"; } }
.glyphicon-share-alt              { &:before { content: "\e095"; } }
.glyphicon-resize-full            { &:before { content: "\e096"; } }
.glyphicon-resize-small           { &:before { content: "\e097"; } }
.glyphicon-exclamation-sign       { &:before { content: "\e101"; } }
.glyphicon-gift                   { &:before { content: "\e102"; } }
.glyphicon-leaf                   { &:before { content: "\e103"; } }
.glyphicon-fire                   { &:before { content: "\e104"; } }
.glyphicon-eye-open               { &:before { content: "\e105"; } }
.glyphicon-eye-close              { &:before { content: "\e106"; } }
.glyphicon-warning-sign           { &:before { content: "\e107"; } }
.glyphicon-plane                  { &:before { content: "\e108"; } }
.glyphicon-calendar               { &:before { content: "\e109"; } }
.glyphicon-random                 { &:before { content: "\e110"; } }
.glyphicon-comment                { &:before { content: "\e111"; } }
.glyphicon-magnet                 { &:before { content: "\e112"; } }
.glyphicon-chevron-up             { &:before { content: "\e113"; } }
.glyphicon-chevron-down           { &:before { content: "\e114"; } }
.glyphicon-retweet                { &:before { content: "\e115"; } }
.glyphicon-shopping-cart          { &:before { content: "\e116"; } }
.glyphicon-folder-close           { &:before { content: "\e117"; } }
.glyphicon-folder-open            { &:before { content: "\e118"; } }
.glyphicon-resize-vertical        { &:before { content: "\e119"; } }
.glyphicon-resize-horizontal      { &:before { content: "\e120"; } }
.glyphicon-hdd                    { &:before { content: "\e121"; } }
.glyphicon-bullhorn               { &:before { content: "\e122"; } }
.glyphicon-bell                   { &:before { content: "\e123"; } }
.glyphicon-certificate            { &:before { content: "\e124"; } }
.glyphicon-thumbs-up              { &:before { content: "\e125"; } }
.glyphicon-thumbs-down            { &:before { content: "\e126"; } }
.glyphicon-hand-right             { &:before { content: "\e127"; } }
.glyphicon-hand-left              { &:before { content: "\e128"; } }
.glyphicon-hand-up                { &:before { content: "\e129"; } }
.glyphicon-hand-down              { &:before { content: "\e130"; } }
.glyphicon-circle-arrow-right     { &:before { content: "\e131"; } }
.glyphicon-circle-arrow-left      { &:before { content: "\e132"; } }
.glyphicon-circle-arrow-up        { &:before { content: "\e133"; } }
.glyphicon-circle-arrow-down      { &:before { content: "\e134"; } }
.glyphicon-globe                  { &:before { content: "\e135"; } }
.glyphicon-wrench                 { &:before { content: "\e136"; } }
.glyphicon-tasks                  { &:before { content: "\e137"; } }
.glyphicon-filter                 { &:before { content: "\e138"; } }
.glyphicon-briefcase              { &:before { content: "\e139"; } }
.glyphicon-fullscreen             { &:before { content: "\e140"; } }
.glyphicon-dashboard              { &:before { content: "\e141"; } }
.glyphicon-paperclip              { &:before { content: "\e142"; } }
.glyphicon-heart-empty            { &:before { content: "\e143"; } }
.glyphicon-link                   { &:before { content: "\e144"; } }
.glyphicon-phone                  { &:before { content: "\e145"; } }
.glyphicon-pushpin                { &:before { content: "\e146"; } }
.glyphicon-usd                    { &:before { content: "\e148"; } }
.glyphicon-gbp                    { &:before { content: "\e149"; } }
.glyphicon-sort                   { &:before { content: "\e150"; } }
.glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet       { &:before { content: "\e151"; } }
.glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet-alt   { &:before { content: "\e152"; } }
.glyphicon-sort-by-order          { &:before { content: "\e153"; } }
.glyphicon-sort-by-order-alt      { &:before { content: "\e154"; } }
.glyphicon-sort-by-attributes     { &:before { content: "\e155"; } }
.glyphicon-sort-by-attributes-alt { &:before { content: "\e156"; } }
.glyphicon-unchecked              { &:before { content: "\e157"; } }
.glyphicon-expand                 { &:before { content: "\e158"; } }
.glyphicon-collapse-down          { &:before { content: "\e159"; } }
.glyphicon-collapse-up            { &:before { content: "\e160"; } }
.glyphicon-log-in                 { &:before { content: "\e161"; } }
.glyphicon-flash                  { &:before { content: "\e162"; } }
.glyphicon-log-out                { &:before { content: "\e163"; } }
.glyphicon-new-window             { &:before { content: "\e164"; } }
.glyphicon-record                 { &:before { content: "\e165"; } }
.glyphicon-save                   { &:before { content: "\e166"; } }
.glyphicon-open                   { &:before { content: "\e167"; } }
.glyphicon-saved                  { &:before { content: "\e168"; } }
.glyphicon-import                 { &:before { content: "\e169"; } }
.glyphicon-export                 { &:before { content: "\e170"; } }
.glyphicon-send                   { &:before { content: "\e171"; } }
.glyphicon-floppy-disk            { &:before { content: "\e172"; } }
.glyphicon-floppy-saved           { &:before { content: "\e173"; } }
.glyphicon-floppy-remove          { &:before { content: "\e174"; } }
.glyphicon-floppy-save            { &:before { content: "\e175"; } }
.glyphicon-floppy-open            { &:before { content: "\e176"; } }
.glyphicon-credit-card            { &:before { content: "\e177"; } }
.glyphicon-transfer               { &:before { content: "\e178"; } }
.glyphicon-cutlery                { &:before { content: "\e179"; } }
.glyphicon-header                 { &:before { content: "\e180"; } }
.glyphicon-compressed             { &:before { content: "\e181"; } }
.glyphicon-earphone               { &:before { content: "\e182"; } }
.glyphicon-phone-alt              { &:before { content: "\e183"; } }
.glyphicon-tower                  { &:before { content: "\e184"; } }
.glyphicon-stats                  { &:before { content: "\e185"; } }
.glyphicon-sd-video               { &:before { content: "\e186"; } }
.glyphicon-hd-video               { &:before { content: "\e187"; } }
.glyphicon-subtitles              { &:before { content: "\e188"; } }
.glyphicon-sound-stereo           { &:before { content: "\e189"; } }
.glyphicon-sound-dolby            { &:before { content: "\e190"; } }
.glyphicon-sound-5-1              { &:before { content: "\e191"; } }
.glyphicon-sound-6-1              { &:before { content: "\e192"; } }
.glyphicon-sound-7-1              { &:before { content: "\e193"; } }
.glyphicon-copyright-mark         { &:before { content: "\e194"; } }
.glyphicon-registration-mark      { &:before { content: "\e195"; } }
.glyphicon-cloud-download         { &:before { content: "\e197"; } }
.glyphicon-cloud-upload           { &:before { content: "\e198"; } }
.glyphicon-tree-conifer           { &:before { content: "\e199"; } }
.glyphicon-tree-deciduous         { &:before { content: "\e200"; } }
.glyphicon-cd                     { &:before { content: "\e201"; } }
.glyphicon-save-file              { &:before { content: "\e202"; } }
.glyphicon-open-file              { &:before { content: "\e203"; } }
.glyphicon-level-up               { &:before { content: "\e204"; } }
.glyphicon-copy                   { &:before { content: "\e205"; } }
.glyphicon-paste                  { &:before { content: "\e206"; } }
// The following 2 Glyphicons are omitted for the time being because
// they currently use Unicode codepoints that are outside the
// Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP). Older buggy versions of WebKit can't handle
// non-BMP codepoints in CSS string escapes, and thus can't display these two icons.
// Notably, the bug affects some older versions of the Android Browser.
// More info: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10106
// .glyphicon-door                   { &:before { content: "\1f6aa"; } }
// .glyphicon-key                    { &:before { content: "\1f511"; } }
.glyphicon-alert                  { &:before { content: "\e209"; } }
.glyphicon-equalizer              { &:before { content: "\e210"; } }
.glyphicon-king                   { &:before { content: "\e211"; } }
.glyphicon-queen                  { &:before { content: "\e212"; } }
.glyphicon-pawn                   { &:before { content: "\e213"; } }
.glyphicon-bishop                 { &:before { content: "\e214"; } }
.glyphicon-knight                 { &:before { content: "\e215"; } }
.glyphicon-baby-formula           { &:before { content: "\e216"; } }
.glyphicon-tent                   { &:before { content: "\26fa"; } }
.glyphicon-blackboard             { &:before { content: "\e218"; } }
.glyphicon-bed                    { &:before { content: "\e219"; } }
.glyphicon-apple                  { &:before { content: "\f8ff"; } }
.glyphicon-erase                  { &:before { content: "\e221"; } }
.glyphicon-hourglass              { &:before { content: "\231b"; } }
.glyphicon-lamp                   { &:before { content: "\e223"; } }
.glyphicon-duplicate              { &:before { content: "\e224"; } }
.glyphicon-piggy-bank             { &:before { content: "\e225"; } }
.glyphicon-scissors               { &:before { content: "\e226"; } }
.glyphicon-bitcoin                { &:before { content: "\e227"; } }
.glyphicon-yen                    { &:before { content: "\00a5"; } }
.glyphicon-ruble                  { &:before { content: "\20bd"; } }
.glyphicon-scale                  { &:before { content: "\e230"; } }
.glyphicon-ice-lolly              { &:before { content: "\e231"; } }
.glyphicon-ice-lolly-tasted       { &:before { content: "\e232"; } }
.glyphicon-education              { &:before { content: "\e233"; } }
.glyphicon-option-horizontal      { &:before { content: "\e234"; } }
.glyphicon-option-vertical        { &:before { content: "\e235"; } }
.glyphicon-menu-hamburger         { &:before { content: "\e236"; } }
.glyphicon-modal-window           { &:before { content: "\e237"; } }
.glyphicon-oil                    { &:before { content: "\e238"; } }
.glyphicon-grain                  { &:before { content: "\e239"; } }
.glyphicon-sunglasses             { &:before { content: "\e240"; } }
.glyphicon-text-size              { &:before { content: "\e241"; } }
.glyphicon-text-color             { &:before { content: "\e242"; } }
.glyphicon-text-background        { &:before { content: "\e243"; } }
.glyphicon-object-align-top       { &:before { content: "\e244"; } }
.glyphicon-object-align-bottom    { &:before { content: "\e245"; } }
.glyphicon-object-align-horizontal{ &:before { content: "\e246"; } }
.glyphicon-object-align-left      { &:before { content: "\e247"; } }
.glyphicon-object-align-vertical  { &:before { content: "\e248"; } }
.glyphicon-object-align-right     { &:before { content: "\e249"; } }
.glyphicon-triangle-right         { &:before { content: "\e250"; } }
.glyphicon-triangle-left          { &:before { content: "\e251"; } }
.glyphicon-triangle-bottom        { &:before { content: "\e252"; } }
.glyphicon-triangle-top           { &:before { content: "\e253"; } }
.glyphicon-console                { &:before { content: "\e254"; } }
.glyphicon-superscript            { &:before { content: "\e255"; } }
.glyphicon-subscript              { &:before { content: "\e256"; } }
.glyphicon-menu-left              { &:before { content: "\e257"; } }
.glyphicon-menu-right             { &:before { content: "\e258"; } }
.glyphicon-menu-down              { &:before { content: "\e259"; } }
.glyphicon-menu-up                { &:before { content: "\e260"; } }
```

Comment: The thing is, the .css files are exactly the same both on the local server and the hosted library. I checked the unminified version of bootstrap.css as well, and it does have quotes around the content as one would expect. Here's a [diff](https://www.diffchecker.com/ebfpexcv) of the two minified files, with the local file on the left and the one from MaxCDN on the right.

Comment: Try pulling down the font files from the CDN again to make sure you have the latest in your local directory.  The files may exist, but the icons may not be in the font files you have.

Comment: I actually just tried that about half an hour ago. I downloaded the .eot font at https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot and replaced my local file and still nothing.

Answer (score 4):

Need to add MIME types to IIS/IIS Express for .woff and .woff2

Extension: .woff
MIME Type: application/font-woff

Extension: .woff2
MIME Type: application/font-woff

It solved the problem for me.

Comment: This solved my problem as well with .woff2 font on Windows 7 running IIS 7.x locally. Previously with Bootstrap v3.2.x the glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2 font was not loading (in Chrome anyway). Though for type, I used application/x-font-woff2 since that's what matched the type for .woff. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

1- ON IIS EXPRESS
Open this file

```
"C:\Users\ {YourUserName} \Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config"
```

Find this line :

```
<mimeMap fileExtension=.woff" mimeType="font/x-woff"/>
```

and add this to next line :

```
<mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="font/x-woff"/>
```

Save file.

2.ON IIS 7-8

```
<system.webServer>
   <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
   </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```